# Vertically Align Text With Bootstrap Radio Button

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I am having a problem with Bootstrap radio inputs in which I can't seem to get the alignment to be vertically in the middle with the text.

```
    <div class="tab-content">

    <div class="tab-pane" id="Type">

    <form>

        <div class="form-group">

              <input type="radio"               
               value="Server"
               checked="checked"
               class="form-control" 
               style="width: 34px; display: inline-block" />

            <label for="WindowsServer">Windows Server / PC</label><br />                                
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong or what I can do to fix this?

Comment: add `input` field inside `label`

Comment: Tried that, but still have the same problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Got this sorted - after much playing around, I added a style:

```
input{
vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Now the radio and text are aligned perfectly!

Comment: i gave you reply with my answer but don't know why it was not publishing but now you can use this and still any error then let me know..thanx